# What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: debugging, http, google-chrome, developer-tools, web-developer-toolbar

What would cause a page to be canceled? I have a screenshot of the Chrome Developer Tools.

[image: Canceled Resource]

This happens often but not every time. It seems like once some other resources are cached, a page refresh will load the LeftPane.aspx. And what's really odd is this only happens in Google Chrome, not Internet Explorer 8. Any ideas why Chrome would cancel a request?

Comment: You might be able to get more details from a [net-internals](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/providing-network-details) trace.  I had a similar issue and found in my case that canceled was `net::ERR_ABORTED` under the covers.  If that's the case, [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/Fal1ZJnTgGQ/UDdxbrf_Rv4J) explains that "net::ERR_ABORTED is intended to only be generated when a user action causes
a load to be interrupted.  This can happen when a new navigation interrupts an existing one, or when the user clicks the STOP button."

Comment: Thanks. In my case it's not the user because I am the user. The page does have (too) many frames. Maybe the frame src gets changed? It's just odd that I have never seen it happen in IE. I'll look into net-internals.

Comment: @nondescript1 I did the capture while reproducing the bug and dumped to a file. Now I have a 18,000 line json file. What am I looking for?

Comment: You can view the events in net-internals on the events panel.  Look for the related request in the events table and you should see additional details on the right panel.  And, in the quote about ERR_ABORTED, I was also much more interested in the idea of an interrupting navigation than a user action :)

Comment: @nondescript1 You were right; it was `net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)`. My temporary fix right now is with a setTimeout that checks if the frame loaded. If it didn't load then it sets the src again. Could caching play a part in this bug?

Comment: I honestly don't know.  Actually came across your question when I was looking for more information on status=canceled myself, which is the reason why I'm only adding comments and not an answer ;). I have no reason to think it's related to caching.  I'm more suspicious of another navigation initiated someone in the page.  When I saw this, I was trying to initiate a download with window.open() that caused another server request to be canceled.  In my case, Firefox didn't have this issue but Chrome did.

Comment: Just so it doesn't go without saying, one possible cause of "(cancelled)" in the status column -- though definitely not the only possible cause -- is that the URL as given has returned a 404 or other error.  Force-refresh the URL in another tab a few times to make sure it is loading consistently.

Comment: @rakslice turned out to be a 404 - wonder why Chrome wouldn't just say that. Thanks.

Comment: I was having the same problem.  Switching to the "Console" tab within Chrome's Developer Tools provided additional information as to why the request is being canceled.  In my case it was an issue with CORS.

Answer (score 744, accepted):

We fought a similar problem where Chrome was canceling requests to load things within frames or iframes, but only intermittently and it seemed dependent on the computer and/or the speed of the internet connection.

This information is a few months out of date, but I built Chromium from scratch, dug through the source to find all the places where requests could get cancelled, and slapped breakpoints on all of them to debug. From memory, the only places where Chrome will cancel a request:

- The DOM element that caused the request to be made got deleted (i.e. an IMG is being loaded, but before the load happened, you deleted the IMG node)
- You did something that made loading the data unnecessary. (i.e. you started loading a iframe, then changed the src or overwrite the contents)
- There are lots of requests going to the same server, and a network problem on earlier requests showed that subsequent requests weren't going to work (DNS lookup error, earlier (same) request resulted e.g. HTTP 400 error code, etc)

In our case we finally traced it down to one frame trying to append HTML to another frame, that sometimes happened before the destination frame even loaded. Once you touch the contents of an iframe, it can no longer load the resource into it (how would it know where to put it?) so it cancels the request.

Comment: Very informative, thank you. I have a hard time reproducing this bug because once things get cached, it doesn't happen. If set a breakpoint in my javascript, it doesn't happen. Your first bullet point is probably not the problem because I don't see a element being deleted. I know for a fact it isn't bullet point 3. What do you mean by "Once you touch the contents of an iframe, it can no longer load the resource into it"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @styfle Suppose you have two frames `<frame name="A" src="..."> & <frame name="B" src="...">`  The src of A does something like `parent.frames[1].document.write("Copyright Notice")`. If B loads before A, A will append the copyright notice to B. If A loads first, it writes to an empty frame, which cancels the load of B.

Comment: Interesting. So I need to find all `document.write`s to that frame and make sure they only write when the frame is loaded. I'll mark this as the correct answer since you answered the meaning of that status.

Comment: @styfle Yes, but it can be things other than document.write, too. Anything that tries writing to the frame like appendChild or similar would likely cause this. You might want to create an onLoad handler in each frame that writes `true` to some variable, then other frames look for that first before touching anything.

Comment: I have also had horrible problems with this. One thing that I have found that does consistently trigger this if the AJAX response has a status code 301/302 and the redirect URL is on another domain. This is a consistent reproduction of the problem for me.

Comment: I'm having the same pseudo-issue (it does not bother me tbh), my scenario is following: click "Create PDF" button in my app, this opens new tab and Chrome pops up a "Save as" dialog, when I save the PDF the tab is destroyed; which is probably why the request is marked with statuc:cancelled, despite the resulting file appearing to be OK (i.e. I get a healthy PDF)

Comment: For me, it happened when a link action got cancelled, like when I clicked on a link with an unknown protocol (eg. `WhatsApp://`) and that link had a JSON request attached to it via Javascript. The link action getting cancelled also cancelled the according onclick javascript event. Weird, but feasable.

Comment: Only to add to the answer: I have this problem when I called a request and after that I did a ``window.location.reload();`` outside of the callback.

Comment: Thanks for this! I think mine was the third case, as I'm trying to load a resource that is proxied, and this is the only reference I've found so far. Will try to investigate further, and post here if I find something relevant.

Comment: So helpful! I spent a whole day trying to understand this... In my case it was "You did something that made loading the data unnecessary. (i.e. you started loading a iframe, then changed the src or overwrite the contents)"  Something similar... but this cleared the issue!

Comment: I had this issue, eventually discovered that the iframe from which the ajax request was being made was being removed before the request completed.

Comment: For me it was iframe append to body then immediately removed from body. I put a line break and issue was not there. So put some timeout (15 ms) and overcome it.
@whamma it is really motivating the way you tackled the issue.
Thanks for such a great in-depth details. :-)

Comment: Just to add to this I've found another where I was doing a 302 redirect after a form post, the request appeared as cancelled in Chrome but the server logs showed a 302 response. It was because the `Location` header had an incorrect url: `localhost:8080` rather than `http://localhost:8080`. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Atlassians help desk widget loads an iframe and exhibits exact behavior in this answer. I couldn't statically load the Atlassian "embed.js" and went this route, well after page load time: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Desk-questions/Dynamically-Embedding-Service-Desk-Widget/qaq-p/899686

Comment: Just had this happen in a React app where the component that made the request got taken out of the DOM. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's worth noting to future readers, several modern frameworks like React may be cancelling requests to emulate the behavior of the web browser, but when your React component is destroyed, it's not chrome making the decision to cancel the request, since to Chrome, the DOM element wasn't initiating the request like an `img` tag would do, the request was initiated by arbitrary javascript.

Comment: It's really terrifying thet you have to dig into the browser's source code to know why this is happening, especially because I see this almost every day in devtool. Are there no documentation or something like about this?

Comment: Yes! thanks for this. Bullet 1 was exactly my problem.
I had a button that was triggering several API calls. Additionally, this button was rerouting the page to a different route - in essence, deleting the button from the DOM before the api calls were resolved. My solutions was ensuring the resolution of the api calls before rerouting. Otherwise the apis were cancelling out.

Answer (score 78):

status=canceled may happen also on ajax requests on JavaScript events:

```html
<script>
  $("#call_ajax").on("click", function(event){
     $.ajax({
        ...    
     });
  });
</script>

<button id="call_ajax">call</button>
```

The event successfully sends the request, but is is canceled then (but processed by the server). The reason is, the  elements submit forms on click events, no matter if you make any ajax requests on the same click event.

To prevent request from being cancelled, JavaScript `event.preventDefault();` has to be called:

```html
<script>
  $("#call_ajax").on("click", function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        ...    
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This saved me, was the problem in my case where I used angular's `ng-click` on a button with `type="submit"` and then did some networking in the called function. Chrome kept canceling that request...

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. Any other hints?

Comment: Vaov saved me too! For an angular ng-click event I had nested $http requests and second one was being canceled. After setting the prevent default line it started working again, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew it was not CORS or a DOM issue. Perhaps @whamma could update their answer to include this as possible cause for completeness :)

Comment: Hail the lord !! Sir, you are an absolute genius !! I have been saved !!

Comment: Further to Robin's answer above, I had the same thing in react. Having both a submit event and an onClick event on the button. One request was cancelling the other.`<CButton onClick={loginClicked} color="primary" className="px-4" type='submit'>Login</CButton>`

Answer (score 50):

NB: Make sure you don't have **any wrapping form elements**.

I had a similar issue where my button with onclick={} was wrapped in a form element. When clicking the button the form is also submitted, and that messed it all up...

Comment: This was the root cause for me - a button triggered POST twice. I didn't want to move the button out of the form element because of CSS stuff so this was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms/10836076#10836076

Comment: Same issue. To clarify, i had a button contained in a form with a type of submit, but had an onclick that was doing a jquery form submit, ajax submit. It worked in FF, but failed in chome and IE, and drove me nuts until i found it.

Comment: This fixes an issue that happened to me in a Vue.js app where a `@click` event was bound to a `<button>` element inside a form wrapper. Avoid doing this unless you are using Vue's `@submit.prevent` event modifier.

Comment: This was the case for me. By adding a `type="button"` to my button tag, the form wasn't submitted and the cancelled event was avoided.

Comment: Excellent advice! Thanks for saving time

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I found that it is jquery global timeout settings, a jquery plugin setup global timeout to 500ms, so that when the request exceed 500ms, chrome will cancel the request.

Comment: Running into the same issue. In my case it is a local WordPress/WooCommerce development with VirtualBox guest server, and some WooCommerce AJAX requests have a predefined AJAX timeout of 5000ms. If someone ran into the same issue, this timeout defined in `includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php` file.

Answer (score 16):

Another thing to look out for could be the AdBlock extension, or extensions in general.

But "a lot" of people have AdBlock....

To rule out extension(s) open a new tab in incognito making sure that "allow in incognito is off" for the extention(s) you want to test.

Comment: Exactly what happened. Turned on noscript plugin and suddenly iFrame was not loading anymore.

Comment: For me, it was Hola plugin. After disabling, requests are no longer cancelled.

Comment: In my case it was "JavaScript Errors Notifier" chrome extension

Comment: I tried looking into everything and still no luck with Angular 8, disabled all extensions and still on slow 3G network previous calls are canceled. :(

Answer (score 13):

You might want to check the "X-Frame-Options" header tag.  If its set to SAMEORIGIN or DENY then the iFrame insertion will be canceled by Chrome (and other browsers) per the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

Also, note that some browsers support the ALLOW-FROM setting but Chrome does not.

To resolve this, you will need to remove the "X-Frame-Options" header tag.  This could leave you open to [clickjacking attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) so you will need to decide what the risks are and how to mitigate them.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. This thread has good answers on how to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options

Answer (score 10):

Here's what happened to me: the server was returning a malformed "Location" header for a 302 redirect.
Chrome failed to tell me this, of course. I opened the page in firefox, and immediately discovered the problem.
Nice to have multiple tools :)

Comment: Although very obvious as to the reason, but still, this is actually a very useful answer. I was editing some old coffeescript code, and had completely forgotten that single quotes didn't do the `#{}` interpolation, so the resulting url were malformed. But Chrome didn't tell me anything about it.

Answer (score 8):

Another place we've encountered the `(canceled)` status is in a particular TLS certificate misconfiguration.  If a site such as `https://www.example.com` is misconfigured such that the certificate does not include the `www.` but is valid for `https://example.com`, chrome will cancel this request and automatically redirect to the latter site.  This is *not* the case for Firefox.

Currently valid example: https://www.pthree.org/

Comment: can you basically just redirect from non certificate domain to certificate'ed one ?
from naked to www? or you always see either canceled or certificate error?

Answer (score 6):

A cancelled request happened to me when redirecting between secure and non-secure pages on separate domains within an iframe.  The redirected request showed in dev tools as a "cancelled" request.

I have a page with an iframe containing a form hosted by my payment gateway. When the form in the iframe was submitted, the payment gateway would redirect back to a URL on my server.  The redirect recently stopped working and ended up as a "cancelled" request instead.

It seems that Chrome (I was using Windows 7 Chrome 30.0.1599.101) no longer allowed a redirect within the iframe to go to a non-secure page on a separate domain. To fix it, I just made sure any redirected requests in the iframe were always sent to secure URLs.

When I created a simpler test page with only an iframe, there was a warning in the console (which I had previous missed or maybe didn't show up):

```
[Blocked] The page at https://mydomain.com/Payment/EnterDetails ran insecure content from http://mydomain.com/Payment/Success
```

The redirect turned into a cancelled request in Chrome on PC, Mac and Android. I don't know if it is specific to my website setup (SagePay Low Profile) or if something has changed in Chrome.

Comment: I am seeing almost identical behaviour in Chrome 30 when using Datacash hosted payment services, but in my case the POST from the 3dsecure site to the Datacash site is canceled, despite both being https. It is proving to be something of a mystery.

Answer (score 5):

If you use axios it can help you

`// change timeout delay:
instance.defaults.timeout = 2500;`

https://github.com/axios/axios#config-order-of-precedence

Answer (score 4):

Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m consistently cancels image loads if I am using the [Mobile Emulation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) pointed at my localhost; specifically with **User Agent spoofing *on*** (vs. just Screen settings).

When I turn User Agent spoofing off; image requests aren't canceled, I see the images.

I still don't understand why; in the former case, where the request is cancelled the Request Headers (CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown) have only

- Accept
- Cache-Control
- Pragma
- Referer
- User-Agent

In the latter case, all of those plus others like:

- Cookie
- Connection
- Host
- Accept-Encoding
- Accept-Language

*Shrug*

Answer (score 4):

I got this error in Chrome when I redirected via JavaScript:

```
<script>
    window.location.href = "devhost:88/somepage";
</script>
```

As you see **I forgot the 'http://'**. After I added it, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another case of request being canceled by chrome, which I just encountered, which is not covered by any of answers up there.

In a nutshell
Self-signed certificate not being trusted on my android phone.

Details
We are in development/debug phase. The url is pointing to a self-signed host. The code is like:

```
location.href = 'https://some.host.com/some/path'
```

Chrome just canceled the request silently, leaving no clue for newbie to web development like myself to fix the issue. Once I downloaded and installed the certificate using the android phone the issue is gone.

Answer (score 4):

If you make use of some Observable-based HTTP requests like those built-in in Angular (2+), then the HTTP request can be canceled when observable gets canceled (common thing when you're using RxJS 6 `switchMap` operator to combine the streams). In most cases it's enough to use `mergeMap` operator instead, if you want the request to complete.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I had an anchor with click event like

```
<a href="" onclick="somemethod($index, hour, $event)">
```

Inside click event I had some network call, Chrome cancelling the request. The anchor has `href` with `""` means, it reloads the page and the same time it has click event with network call that gets cancelled. Whenever i replace the `href` with void like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="somemethod($index, hour, $event)">
```

The problem went away!

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same issue, somewhere deep in our code we had this pseudocode:

- create an iframe
- onload of iframe submit a form
- After 2 seconds, remove the iframe

thus, when the server takes more than 2 seconds to respond the iframe to which the server was writing the response to, was removed, but the response was still to be written , but there was no iframe to write , thus chrome cancelled the request, thus to avoid this I made sure that the iframe is removed only after the response is over, or you can change the target to "_blank".
Thus one of the reason is:
**when the resource(iframe in my case) that you are writing something in, is removed or deleted before you stop writing to it, the request will be cancelled**

Comment: thanks, you save my time! I had an issue with iframe but couldn't realize why it was canceled. And your research helped me to debug and find the issue in fast re-rendering during iframe opening.

Answer (score 2):

I have embedded all types of font as well as **woff**, **woff2**, **ttf** when I embed a web font in style sheet. Recently I noticed that Chrome cancels request to **ttf** and **woff** when **woff2** is present. I use Chrome version 66.0.3359.181 right now but I am not sure when Chrome started canceling of extra font types.

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem having tag `<button>` in the form, that was supposed to send ajax request from js. But this request was canceled, due to browser, that sends form automatically on any click on `button` inside the form.

So if you realy want to use `button`  instead of regular `div` or `span` on the page, and you want to send form throw js - you should setup a listener with `preventDefault` function.

e.g.

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    //do ajax
    $.ajax({

     ...
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same thing with two CSS files that were stored in another folder outside my main css folder. I'm using Expression Engine and found that the issue was in the rules in my htaccess file. I just added the folder to one of my conditions and it fixed it. Here's an example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(images|css|js|new_folder|favicon.ico)
```

So it might be worth you checking your htaccess file for any potential conflicts

Answer (score 1):

happened to me the same when calling a. js file with $. ajax, and make an ajax request, what I did was call normally.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the code to show e-mail client window caused Chrome to stop loading images:

```
document.location.href = mailToLink;
```

moving it to $(window).load(function () {...}) instead of $(function () {...}) helped.

Answer (score 1):

In can this helps anybody I came across the cancelled status when I left out the return false; in the form submit. This caused the ajax send to be immediately followed by the submit action, which overwrote the current page. The code is shown below, with the important return false at the end.

```
$('form').submit(function() {

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
    var data = $('form').serialize();
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

    if ($('form').valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: submitSuccess,
            fail: submitFailed
        });
    }
    return false;       //needed to stop default form submit action
});
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had an `a` tag inside a `div` tag. `div` had `onclick="location='http://mydestination.org/'"` and `a` tag had the same URL in `href`. That caused the target page to be loaded two times and the first load was canceled by Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had timeout into axios instance

```
const axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    timeout: requestTimeout,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming from LoopbackJS and attempting to use the custom stream method like provided in their chart example. I was getting this error using a `PersistedModel`, switching to a basic `Model` fixed my issue of the `eventsource` status cancelling out.

Again, this is specifically for the loopback api. And since this is a top answer and top on google i figured i'de throw this in the mix of answers.

Answer (score 0):

For me 'canceled' status was because the file did not exist. Strange why chrome does not show `404`.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as an incorrect path for me.  I would suggest the first step in debugging would be to see if you can load the file independently of ajax etc.

Answer (score 0):

The requests might have been blocked by a tracking protection plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when loading 300 images as background images. I'm guessing once first one timed out, it cancelled all the rest, or reached max concurrent request. need to implement a 5-at-a-time

Answer (score 0):

One the reasons could be that the [XMLHttpRequest.abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) was called somewhere in the code, in this case, the request will have the `cancelled` status in the Chrome Developer tools Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it started coming after chrome 76 update.

Due to some issue in my JS code, window.location was getting updated multiple times which resulted in canceling previous request.
Although the issue was present from before, chrome started cancelling request after update to version 76.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when updating a record. Inside the save() i was prepping the rawdata taken from the form to match the database format (doing a lot of mapping of enums values, etc), and this intermittently cancels the put request. i resolved it by taking out the data prepping from the save() and creating a dedicated dataPrep() method out of it. I turned this dataPrep into async and await all the memory intensive data conversion. I then return the prepped data to the save() method that i could use in the http put client. I made sure i await on dataPrep() before calling the put method:

await dataToUpdate = await dataPrep();
http.put(apiUrl, dataToUpdate);

This solved the intermittent cancelling of request.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause of the problem was yet another one.

My application is sitting behind a proxy, and Chrome requests were being sent with the [If-Modified-Since HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top). When this header is present the exepcted behavior is:

> the server will send back the requested resource, with a 200 status, only if it has been last modified after the given date. If the request has not been modified since, the response will be a 304 without any body;

The Proxy was failing to meet this expectation, responding with a 304 status code but a non-empty body, thus causing the request to be cancelled.

After fixing the proxy behavior requests worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Content Security Policy headers for me! You can quickly rule out this possibility by checking the Chrome Dev Tools Console, if it's CSP problems there will be errors showing in the console. In .Net you can fix this either by adding headers in the web.config file or in code.

> Refused to send form data to 'https://www.mysite.mydomain/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' *.otherdomain www.thirdparty.co.uk".

Here's the web.config fix for the above error:

```html
<cspConfiguration>
        <directives>
            <directive name="form-action" allowedSources="'self' *.mydomain>
            </directive>
        </directives>
</cspConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

in strict point of view of Angular :

it happens when, you're not able to properly break at the code level.

suppose, request1 is out, and its response also came,
after that, nested request2 also went out and its response also came, and directly we're breaking out of the loop, without properly destroying the subscription of request1,

at that time, it happens