# HTTP request is getting cancelled

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to upload a file to a remote server. My request is not hitting there correctly and I see the Status as (canceled) in the network. I dont see my datas are passing in the network. PFB the abstract code

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (xhr) {
    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            ///do blah blah
        }
    };

}

var form = new FormData();
form.append("tpiFiles", fileData);

form.append("COOKIE", 'COOKIE=' + $.cookie('COOKIE'));
xhr.send(form);
```

All helps are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is probably due to cross domain requests, am i right?

Comment: Check x-domain requests as stated by haim770, also request-length may be an issue (eg. file to upload is too big): in this case you should check the application server settings on remote server.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools ?