# XML Http GET Request for local file keeps cancelling

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to run "inherited" code and since I'm fairly new to HTML & javascript I keep running into annoying little issues (that's how you learn :D ).
I have a GET request that is meant to load an mp4 file from a server, but for the sake of debugging and practice, I'm trying to load it from a local directory. I enabled the "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag on my chrome, so I know it's not a [SOP issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). I can't figure out why, the request is sent 3 times, ALWAYS the first and last fail and the 2nd doesn't, but the file is not loaded.

here's a simplified version of the code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', currentFileName, true);
// currentFileName is an mp4 in the same directory
req.responseType = 'blob';

req.onload = function () {
    // Onload is triggered even on 404
    // so we need to check the status code
    if (this.status === 200) {
        console.log("success!");
        doSomeFunc();
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

here's the network log:
[image]

I looked into many possible solutions (example [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303118/chrome-status-cancelled-on-network-dev-tools-when-playing-html5-video), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/what-does-it-mean-when-an-http-request-returns-status-code-0), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462420/http-request-is-getting-cancelled), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923587/chrome-cancelling-a-xmlhttprequest-and-firing-off-a-successful-one-right-after))
Couldn't find a question where this happens with **local** files.
What might be wrong?

Comment: So how is your code being called?

Comment: You can't make XHR requests to local files, it's a cross-domain request, since XHR works with http(s) protocol, not with file protocol. Setting `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag doesn't circumvent that.