# chrome showing status = canceled in network of developer tool

Tags: jquery

In my app, I am loading two `iframe` simultaneously , namely `main-iframe` and `comment-iframe`,`comment-iframe` is visible to  the users only when `main-iframe` is loaded. once the `main-iframe` is loaded I changed the `src` attribute of `comment-iframe`. howerver sometimes,`main-iframe` keeps loading endlessly, with `status=cancel` message in `developer tool` of chrome.i also found this issue on safari as well.(this issue is not coming in firefox and IE)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13459106/1414562

Answer (score 0):

I  had a similar problem when I tried to change the src of an iframe on submit of a form of the main page: the iframe loading was canceled by chrome.

I think this is related to the fact that form post will change the DOM (as also noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools/13459106#13459106)) of the the page that hosts the iframe.

Maybe, it's only a matter of timing: changing the src the comment-iframe alter the DOM of the page that hosts the iframes too early, so it stops loading the main-frame.