# Serving video files from Play 2.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, streaming, httpresponse, playframework-2.1

I'm attempting to create a controller method that serves a video file backed by some CMS-like database entry. My controller method looks like this:

```
def getVideo(id: Int) = DBAction { request => implicit dbSession =>
  { for {
      dbFile <- fetchDBFile(id)
      fsFile <- fetchFilesystemFile(dbFile)
      rangeOpt <- request.headers.get(RANGE).map(_.replaceAll("bytes=", "").split("-").toList match {
                                case rangeStart :: rangeEnd :: Nil => Some(rangeStart.toLong, rangeEnd.toLong)
                                case rangeStart :: Nil => Some(rangeStart.toLong, fsFile.length())
                                case _ => None
                              })
      (rangeStart, rangeEnd) <- rangeOpt
    } yield SimpleResult(
            header = ResponseHeader(
              status = PARTIAL_CONTENT,
              headers = Map(
                CONTENT_TYPE -> MimeTypes.forExtension("mp4").get,
                ACCEPT_RANGES -> "bytes",
                DATE -> new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").format(new Date()),
                CONTENT_LENGTH -> fsFile.length.toString,
                CONTENT_RANGE -> s"bytes $rangeStart-$rangeEnd/${fsFile.length}",
                CONNECTION -> "keep-alive"
              )
            ),
            body = Enumerator.fromStream(new FileInputStream(fsFile))
          )
  } getOrElse {
    NotFound
  }
}
```

It's mostly based on [two](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1097) [sources](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/-BN2eUXtzjI) to implement the logic to handle the specific byte range request necessary to serve videos.

When using either Chrome or Safari on OS X to access this controller method, the developer tools report that the request is *cancelled* - no response, be it a 200 or 404, is received. I have confirmed that the SimpleResponse is actually returned by this controller action on requests I expect it to deliver a good response, but either Play won't finish the response or my browsers won't accept it. Am I doing something wrong here in response, or have I stumbled upon a bug in the framework?

My Play version is 2.1.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reasons why Chrome cancels requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools#answer-13459106)

The sources you used are more complepete. I show you with code what I spotted:

The response code is not always 206 PARTIAL_CONTENT:

```
val responseCode = if (rangeStart != 0 || rangeEnd != fileLength - 1) 206 else 200
```

Skipping the bytes is missing:

```
val stream = new FileInputStream(file)
stream.skip(rangeStart) # range starts defaults to 0
```

The content range can be the full file and partial:

```
val contentLength = if (responseCode == 206) (rangeEnd - rangeStart + 1) else fileLength
```

So you should not send on every case send the Content-Range header.