# How to check if audio is really playing?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, broadcast

I have [this linked problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools) when I try to get a broadcasted audio via a **pause-play** image.

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="http://ip:port/;" autoplay>
    <!-- Autoplay does not work every time in Chrome -->
</audio>
<img id="pause_play" src="pause.png" onClick="playPause()"/>

<script>
    function playPause(){
        var audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
        // when audio is paused
        if(audio.paused){
            audio.src="http://ip:port/;"; // often cancelled
            audio.load();
            audio.play();
            document.getElementById('pause_play').src="pause.png"; // change image
        }
        // when audio is playing, we set it to pause (this always work)
        else{
            audio.pause();
            audio.src=false;
            audio.load();
            document.getElementById('pause_play').src="play.png" 
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works fine on firefox, but Chrome often cancels my requests. Player image is changing but no sound is playing; and that is not cool.

How to check if audio is really playing ? So that **pause play** will change on the right time.