# Couldn't get response from database with jQuery using PHP post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I cannot get this script work. I try to warn if login that user entered is available. But I cannot manage this script to work:

```
$( "#myRegForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

    var errors = false;
    var userAvi = true;
    var loginInput = $('#login').val();

    if( loginInput == ""){
        $("#errorArea").text('LOGIN CANNOT BE EMPTY!');
        $("#errorArea").fadeOut('15000', function() { });
        $("#errorArea").fadeIn('15000', function() { });

        errors = true;
    }
    else if(loginInput.length < 5 ){
        $("#errorArea").text('LOGIN MUST BE AT LEAST 5 CHARACTERS!');
        $("#errorArea").fadeOut('15000', function() { });
        $("#errorArea").fadeIn('15000', function() { });
        errors = true;
    }
    else if (loginInput.length >=5) {
        $.post('checkLogin.php', {login2: loginInput}, function(result) {

            if(result == "0") {
                alert("this");              
            }
            else {
                alert("that");
            }
        });                
    }

    if (errors==true) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Everything works fine until `loginInput.length >=5` else block. So I assume there is a problem with getting answer from PHP file, but I cannot handle it, though I tried many different ways. Here is `checkLogin.php`'s file (note that jQuery script and PHP file are in the same folder):

```
<?php
include ("bd.php");

$login2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login2']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login='$login2'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  
    //and we send 0 to the ajax request  
    echo 0;     
}   

else{  
    //else if it's not bigger then 0, then it's available '  
    //and we send 1 to the ajax request  
    echo 1;  
}  

?>
```

Comment: Hi @Barell - please see the edit history for my edits that you've overwritten on this question. It's a good idea to refresh your screen prior to making an edit, to ensure you have the latest version (Stack Overflow should update the page via a socket to let you know it has changed - not sure why it did not for you). Also, it's generally thought not to be a good idea to reformat code, as it might mask the source of the problem.

Comment: change your php echo from echo 0 to echo "0"

Comment: @Pluda i guess that's not a problem, but i did and nothing changes =(

Answer (score 0):

You're literally sending the string `'loginInput'`.

change

```
$.post('checkLogin.php', {login2: 'loginInput'}, function(result) {
```

to

```
$.post('checkLogin.php', {login2: loginInput}, function(result) {
```

***Edit***

I would just comment out everything except the following for now and see if that at least works

```
$.post('checkLogin.php', {login2: 'loginInput'}, function(result) { // put loginInput back in quotes

       alert('#'+result+'#');  // # to check for whitespace
    });
```

Comment: that was a typo in a question sry about that, still not getting alert messages

Comment: also, avoid using mysql_*, it is deprecated, can lead you to security issues, use pdo instead

Comment: what do you see in the response of the network tab of the developer console when you submit the form?

Comment: @andrew no error messages, like this part of code is being ignored

Comment: @Amal.A so do you see an ***outgoing*** message in the network tab when you submit the form or nothing at all?

Comment: @andrew as i have another php file that checks forms in servers side i see it's response. But no messages from `checkLogin.php`

Comment: I don't understand, is that what bd.php does? does that produce some output before the expected 0 or 1?

Comment: @andrew it's just used for connection nothing is produced there

Comment: @andrew so i commented out all the code except request and now  i see post message in red color

Comment: if its red it probably gives you a n error code 500? 404?

Comment: I don't know where you're looking but view the page in chrome, hit f12 and view the network tab, it should show you all the info you need

Comment: @andrew, no errors but shows this `Status: Cancelled`

Comment: strange take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include ("bd.php");

$login2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login2']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login='$login2'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  
    //and we send 0 to the ajax request  
    echo "0"; // for you to use if(if(result == "0") you should send a string    
} else {
    //else if it's not bigger then 0, then it's available '
    //and we send 1 to the ajax request
    echo "1";
```

}
?>

Comment: I really appreciate any help i can get but i believe there is no technical difference in using `""` or `''` or not using them as echo function works fine with both of them

Comment: i believe the problem is not the echo function, echo always works, but jquery is waiting for a response, then it has to check if result == "0". I believe echoing just zero is the same as echo false, so in js you would have if(result == false) (sorry if i'm wrong)