# Play Audio from client when message is recieved from socket.io - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, audio

I've searched for a while for a solution to this problem, but haven't found much.

My goal is to recieve a message from a udp client, which the server recieves and forwards to a web client, which plays an audio clip each time a message is recieved.  However, for some reason the audio will not play. If I open the page straight from my directory, the audio can be played, but if I try and access it through localhost it fails to load. Does anyone know of a solution?

Here is the client side javascript.

```
var mySound = new Audio('/public/audio/Bloom.mp3');
mySound.load();
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('message', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#content').text(data);
    mySound.play();
    //document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
});
```

This page is served by server.js, a node.js file using socket.io and express. I don't receive any errors from my console.log. 
Here is the server.js

```
var app = require('express')()
    , server = require('http').Server(app)
    , io =require('socket.io')(server)
    , dgram = require('dgram');

var httpPort = 1234;
var udpPort = 5000;

server.listen(httpPort);

app.use(server.express.static( __dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    var ipAddress = request.socket.remoteAddress;
    console.log("New express connection from: " + ipAddress);
    response.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

var udpSocket = dgram.createSocket('udp4', function(msgBuffer){
    var jsonMessage = JSON.parse(msgBuffer);
    io.sockets.emit('message', JSON.stringify(jsonMessage));
});
udpSocket.bind(udpPort, '127.0.0.1');
```

You can go to this link to see the error chrome has.
http://postimg.org/image/xkv7a2kwb/

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify "through my local network"? Are you on the same machine or another one?

Comment: This may also be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you have incorrect Express config for static files.

From your client-side JavaScript I can see that you store your static files in `public` folder.

So somewhere on the server-side you should have something like this:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('/path/to/public'));
```

Doing this way `http://localhost/public/audio/Bloom.mp3` request will be served with `/path/to/public/audio/Bloom.mp3` file.

**Caveat:**

Since Express 4 there is ["no more app.use(app.router)"](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x#no-more-appuseapprouter) and "All routing methods will be added in the order in which they appear". This means that you have to put the above line of code before first `app.get(...)`, `app.post(...)`, etc.

Hope this information will help someone.

Comment: This clarified it very well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we can upload tone into cloud storage and then use that source like below

```
playAudio() {
let audio = new Audio()
audio.src ='https://res.cloudinary.com/Apple_Notification.mp3'
audio.load()
audio.play()
 }
```

trigger this function in client-side whenever a new message comes in