# How to play a sound from a socket.io event?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, audio, socket.io

I want to play a sound file on the client side whenever the space bar is pushed.

The client side successfully emits the 'bang' event when the space bar is pressed:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    alert(event.keyCode);
if (event.keyCode == 32){
        socket.emit('bang'); 
}
});
```

The server side succesfully prints "bang" in the control.log so hopefully it is also emitting 'play':

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('bang', function(){
    console.log('bang');
    io.emit('play');
  });
});
```

However, back on the client side to play the sound, nothing is happening.
The code I am using is:

```
var sound = new Audio('/public/audio/1.mp3');   

socket.on('play', function () {
    sound.play();   
});
```

Do I need to include something in the body to do with audio or a  in order to use the Audio object.

I have searched this quite thoroughly but I am very new to node.js, html and socket.io.
I tried the advice given here:
[Play Audio from client when message is recieved from socket.io - node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186848/play-audio-from-client-when-message-is-recieved-from-socket-io-node-js)

But when I put in:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('/path/to/public'));
```

'static' became flagged and upon trying to run the code I recieved an error message: 'express is not defined, even though I put it before:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

as advised in that post. I also tried it after and got the same error.

Please help me.

Comment: Why is Socket.io involved in this at all?

Comment: I want to create a web application where users can interact in real time by tapping the space bar to make sounds. I was advised to use socket in order to keep the communication close to instantaneous.

Comment: Try `var sound = new Audio('/audio/1.mp3');`

Comment: I tried this, and also: var sound = new Audio('1.mp3'); with the 1.mp3 file in the main the folder, but neither one worked.

Comment: Where's exactly your `1.mp3` file located?

Comment: The folder containing the project is called "new2", there is one copy in new2/public/audio and now there is also one copy in new2 (not in anysubfolders) alongside index.js and index.html

Comment: You say you get the error `'express is not defined`. Do you have `var express = require('express')` in your code?

Comment: Also try `app.use('/public', express.static('/public'));`

Comment: yes, I do have var express = require('express'). I only get that error message when I try to include: app.use('/public', express.static('/path/to/public'));

Comment: I also am recieving the 'express not defined' error message while using ` app.use('/public', express.static('/public'));' the static part gets highlighted and goes red in my text editor

Comment: Post the errors and/or screenshots, and possibly include all the code that leads up to the point of `app.use('/public'`

Comment: Ok - doing this now. (Will upload as soon as it's done.) Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My code was very messy. Here are all the screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/N066I

Comment: You have `var app=require('express')();` Change it to `var express=require('express'); var app=express();`

Comment: I changed it, and have tried the new configuration with `app.use('/public', express.static('/path/to/public'));' and 
`app.use('/public', express.static('/public'));' - the 'static' in both of them still gets highlighted in red but there is no error message, but still no sound. I also tried it with neither of them and still recieved the same result.

Comment: Could you show the updated screenshots of the errors?

Comment: I am not getting any error messages now that I changed it to: `var express=require('express'); var app=express();` I have managed to make sound happen using a src=url for the audio - shown here: https://imgur.com/6yWa2zW, however, the sound does not play when the spacebar is pressed, it simply continuously loops it (even though `loop="false"`)

Comment: Using a url instead of a file is not ideal though as the whole point of using socket.io was to eliminate webpage loading lag. However, I do not know enough about this stuff to know whether a dropbox url would actually cause such a lag.

Comment: Are you using `var sound = new Audio('/audio/1.mp3');`?

Comment: Your questions are being split into two now: 1. `/audio/1.mp3` is not accessible. And 2. lag in playing the audio. It'd be better to tackle the second issue in a separate question, possibly after solving the first one first. Are you able to access `http://<your-site-or-localhost>/audio/1.mp3`?

Comment: That one did not work. The only way I have gotten sound to happen(albeit not in the correct way) has been from using `<audio id="soun" src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/1.mp3?_subject_uid=115438613&w=AAAwTSudEjoFtlW7TCq8AaAMqFwL3psoRjrF4HyqUMjafQ" autoplay="false" hidden="true" loop="false">` with `var myAudio = document.getElementById("soun");
socket.on('play', function(){
myAudio.play(); 
});`

Comment: How about `http://<your-site-or-localhost>/public/audio/1.mp3`?

Comment: Ah - just saw your most recent comment. Agreed. When I type in http://localhost:3000/audio/1.mp3 into the browser, I get a blank screen with the message: 'Cannot GET /audio/1.mp3'

Comment: How about http://localhost:3000/public/audio/1.mp3

Comment: This also does not work. I also tried localhost:3000/1.mp3, and I also copied the /audio folder directly into the project folder to see if that did anything, but it didn't.

Comment: Try `app.use(express.static('public'));` Try to follow the [guide](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) to see if you're doing anything different. The tutorial you seem to be following is quite old, Express changed a lot between versions 3 and 4, now you simply do `app.listen()` instead of using the `http` module. Perhaps some incompatibilities are arising due to mixing old and new styles.

Comment: Sorry this was a while ago. I eventually solved the issue but using: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you so much for spending so much time helping me. I can imagine it being quite unsatisfying since we didn't get to a resolution but I really appreciated all the help and time you put in. Thank you.