# Chrome - Image not loaded when loading from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to simply load an image on page load.

When i use a simple src it works ok:

```
<img src="url.png" />
```

But when I try to load it from my JS It does not load:

```
<img id="loadImage" src="" />
```

JS:

```
var _img = document.getElementById('loadImage');
_img.src = 'url.png';
```

The url is shown as 'not found'.

I am getting the same error as in this post : [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

I cant seem to solve it, Why is that happening.

Comment: Are you opening the html document on your local filesystem or through a server?

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PJYVz/ Have you checked that you call in javascript correctly? Debugged in browser? Correct URL/URI? What have you tried?

Comment: The url exists, my js is ok, the site is directed to my localhost, wired thing is that its working on IE and fails on chrome

Comment: "Questions ...  __include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it__ in the question itself." Obviously your problem is not reproduceable with the posted code.

Comment: I've done all that @Teemu

Comment: @omri what is your script type `text/jscript` or `text/javascript`. If `text/jscript` then it will work only on IE browsers.

Comment: @omri okay! is there any error in browser's console? any js error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try and save the whole image tag in a variable? This you you are not providing invalid HTML markup like empty `src`.

Just change your HTML to

```
<div id="imageholder"></div>
```

and use this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image_1 = $('<img src="img/url.png" />');
    $("#imageholder").append(image_1);
});
```

Take this fiddle and try :)

### http://jsfiddle.net/aBF67/

### NOTE: I'm using jQuery for that example :)

Answer (score 0):

Try yo create a new Image object and assign it to the src attribute. Example:

```
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = "http://.....jpg";

var _img = document.getElementById('loadImage');
_img.src = imgObj;
```

I hope it helps.