# chrome- status cancelled on network dev tools when playing html5 video

Tags: html, google-chrome, websphere, html5-video

I have a problem in loading a webpage that has a html5 video element in it that runs into a weird problem in chrome. I say it is weird because the behavior is inconsistent.

here is a screenshot to explain my problem...

[image]

this is the side by side comparison of the same page when opened in firefox and chrome. The firefox loads the page as it should but chrome does not load the video when play is clicked. Even IE 11 had no issues in loading the video.

Now let me specify the environment where the problem occurs as well. The whole application is hosted on IHS/ Websphere (test environment-although WAS does all the job- not under my control). The link is,

http://wwwtest.courts.mo.gov/civiceducation/pages/const_proj_home.html

I do have another environment where the site is hosted by tomcat where there is no problem at all no matter what browser is used. The link to that page (the exact page under review) is,

http://www.courts.mo.gov/civiceducation/pages/const_proj_home.html

I would appreciate if someone would help me in understanding what is causing this issue or why. Thanks in advance

UPDATE::: 
durin my research i found this SO post [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools) and found this link which says that it is a chrome bug issue dated april 2013 http://wwwtest.courts.mo.gov/civiceducation/pages/const_proj_home.html  but then why does chrome load the videos when a different webserver(tomcat) is used?

UPDATE #2 ::::

i was able to isolate the problem just to mp4 files.In my section of code that handled the video, I flipped the source tags that pointed to mp4 and webm such that the webm is now listed first...

```
<video id="video1" width="850" height="530" poster="../snapshot/constitution_project_home_video_fullsize.png" controls="controls" preload="none" style="display:none;">
       <source src="../Media/video/webm/const_proj_welcomevideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
       <source type="video/mp4" src="../Media/video/mp4/const_proj_welcomevideo.mp4" />
       If you are seeing this, then your browser does not support the video element. You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please upgrade your browser to improve your experience.
</video>
```

Now the page load works just fine.

Even though this solved my original problem, I would still like to know what is causing this issue.

**UPDATE #3::: Disregard update#2**

I thought that the problem was solved but over the weekend I did not test it and now even webm files are not working. Its cancelling the request again. Only when I have websphere as my app server. Hence in am adding the tag "Websphere" back into the mix. Here is a screenshot now...

[image]

And here is the comparison screenshot between tomcat server and WAS 8.5 side by side on chrome

[image]

I am running out of ideas as my requirement going forward is that the content is going to be hosted on the Websphere server. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @fnt I saw that you had made the revision statting that the question has nothing to do with websphere. Can you please explain the reasoning behind your statement? I added the websphere tag because my issue only occurs when the application is hosted on websphere. It works fine when hosted on tomcat. Thanks

Comment: Seems like this is an existing issue that google has not been able to fix...I was experiencing ridiculously long load times for a simple/small video file in chrome only https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234779

Comment: @almightyBoognish Thanks for the response. I did come across the issue of HTML5 video in general having that problem. Then how come the same page is loading correctly when it is hosted on tomcat instead of websphere. That is what is throwing me off. I have noticed that the video is not working when browsed on an ipad as well (safari)

Comment: I can't give you a solution I'm sure of. But I had the same issue half a year ago hosting a website on IIS server. Everything was fine when I created my website localy. But the deployment to IIS gave me the same problem as you got now. I think I solved the issue by converting my files to the ogg format. (I used this website to convert it: http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg. But you can ofcourse convert it by yourself.) I think it had something to do with the way the server handels the MP4, WEBM and OGG mime-type. I can dive into my history if you want?

Comment: Ditching the MP4 my Chrome switches to loading the WEBM version and succeeds – build 39.0.2171.27 beta-m. As I'm sure not everyone is using the current beta build, it could be useful to take a look at the changelog and reduce the problem to certain builds of Chrome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After researching through a lot of materials thats is available online , the bug report from google for chromium etc, I still was not able to understand what was causing the myriad of inconsistent behavior( some videos worked sometimes- Cached maybe?). But I also found out that the version of chrome that I was using were 32 and 34 respectively on 2 test machines. My workplace network policy also prohibited chrome from updating itself automatically.

Hence I performed a manual update on one of my systems ?(v32 to v38) and after that update things started working the way it was supposed to. I updated my other system as well after that and it worked again.

So I dont know if I can post this as an answer here but to me it is now confirmed that it was a chrome bug that was causing the inconsistent behavior. And simply updating the browser (uninstall/re-install) worked as a solution.

I apologize to those who came here looking for a full fledged solution to this problem only to come here and find out that they have to just update the browser.

And last but not the least-- A BIG THANKS to all to who took time to even read and respond to my issue.