# Google Chrome AJAX GET request: net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)

Tags: ajax, json, google-chrome

Trying to GET JSON response via AJAX call on a page load (using JQuery). Chrome shows 'cancelled' status on network tab and when I try to see more at chrome://net-internals/#events, getting below response

```
43576: URL_REQUEST
https://www.example.com/ajax/data
Start Time: 2014-12-17 11:11:51.370

t=201001 [st=  0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=163]
t=201001 [st=  0]   +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=1]
t=201001 [st=  0]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=1]
                       --> delegate_info = "extension AdBlock"
t=201002 [st=  1]   -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=201002 [st=  1]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=161]
                     --> load_flags = 272695297 (BYPASS_DATA_REDUCTION_PROXY | REPORT_RAW_HEADERS | VALIDATE_CACHE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                     --> method = "GET"
                     --> priority = "LOW"
                     --> url = "https://www.example.com/ajax/data"
t=201003 [st=  2]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=201003 [st=  2]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=201003 [st=  2]      HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=0]
                       --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
t=201003 [st=  2]      HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=201003 [st=  2]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=201003 [st=  2]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=201003 [st=  2]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=1]
t=201004 [st=  3]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                         --> source_dependency = 43578 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=201004 [st=  3]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=201004 [st=  3]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=201004 [st=  3]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                         --> GET /ajax/data HTTP/1.1
                             Host: www.example.com
                             Connection: keep-alive
                             Cache-Control: max-age=0
                             Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
                             X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
                             User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
                             Referer: https://www.example.com/my-referee
                             Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
                             Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,be;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4,ta;q=0.2
                             Cookie: [730 bytes were stripped]
t=201004 [st=  3]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=201004 [st=  3]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=28]
t=201004 [st=  3]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=28]
t=201032 [st= 31]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                         --> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
                             Content-Type: text/html
                             Date: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 11:11:47 GMT
                             Location: http://www.example.com/ajax/data
                             Content-Length: 0
t=201032 [st= 31]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=201032 [st= 31]      HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_INFO  [dt=0]
t=201032 [st= 31]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=201032 [st= 31]     +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=130]
t=201032 [st= 31]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=130]
                         --> delegate_info = "AsyncResourceHandler"
t=201162 [st=161]     -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=201162 [st=161]      CANCELLED
t=201163 [st=162]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                     --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=201164 [st=163]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=201164 [st=163] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Comment: The server redirects from https to http, which are different origins, so the request is blocked by the same origin policy.

Comment: Thanks @RobW. Looks like it. Allowing the url to serve in https solves the problem.

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/q/44367568/632951 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/12009423/632951 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/42319992/632951