# Ajax request net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, google-chrome

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. It only happens every once in a while. I should note that I am on satellite internet if that effects anything. In net-intervals this is what I captured:

```
2725: URL_REQUEST
https://testsite.com/wp-json/api/appointments/delete/1785
Start Time: 2017-06-05 04:40:40.902

t=534396 [st= 0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=68]
              --> priority = "MEDIUM"
              --> url = "https://testsite.com/wp-json/api/appointments/delete/1785"
t=534396 [st= 0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=534396 [st= 0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=67]
                --> load_flags = 34624 (DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES |   DO_NOT_SEND_AUTH_DATA | DO_NOT_SEND_COOKIES | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                --> method = "DELETE"
                --> upload_id = "0"
                --> url = "https://testsite.com/wp-json/api/appointments/delete/1785"
t=534396 [st= 0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=534396 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=534396 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=1]
                  --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
t=534397 [st= 1]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=534397 [st= 1]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                    --> source_dependency = 2727 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=534397 [st= 1]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                    --> source_dependency = 2728 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=534397 [st= 1]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=534397 [st= 1]     +UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT  [dt=0]
t=534397 [st= 1]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT  [dt=0]
                    --> is_chunked = false
                    --> net_error = 0 (?)
                    --> total_size = 2
t=534397 [st= 1]     -UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT
                  --> is_chunked = false
                  --> net_error = 0 (?)
                  --> total_size = 2
t=534397 [st= 1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=66]
t=534397 [st= 1]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_HTTP2_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                    --> :authority: testsite.com
                        :method: DELETE
                        :path: /wp-json/api/appointments/delete/1785
                        :scheme: https
                        accept: application/json
                        accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
                        accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
                        authorization: Bearer [231 bytes were stripped]
                        content-length: 2
                        content-type: application/json
                        origin: http://127.0.0.1
                        referer: http://127.0.0.1/myApp/app/
                        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
t=534397 [st= 1]       +UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                    --> current_position = 0
t=534397 [st= 1]          UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                      --> current_position = 0
t=534397 [st= 1]       -UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ
t=534463 [st=67]        HTTP2_STREAM_ERROR
                    --> description = "ABANDONED (stream_id=51): https://testsite.com/wp-json/api/appointments/delete/1785"
                    --> status = -3
                    --> stream_id = 51
t=534463 [st=67]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
                  --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=534463 [st=67]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=534463 [st=67]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=1]
t=534464 [st=68] -REQUEST_ALIVE
              --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
```

Again, this only happens every once in a while. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm also seeing this but don't know why yet either. Don't suppose you've figured it out in the two days since you've asked the question? :-)

Comment: Nope, I have a feeling it has to do with my satellite internet as coworkers don't see it and they are on fast internet.

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/q/27525161/632951