# MVC Web API 2.0 Request showing Canceled

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have created list of REST Web Services using MVC Web API 2.0, Entity Framework 6.0.

My problem is if i am making call to show list of images using jQuery then my request will automatically canceled see below image
[image]
and it will not showing any result at client side, but my server side code will return the correct result set. see below screen of my server side code:
[image]

I am using following code:
**Model**

```
public partial class MAItem
    {
        public MAItem()
        {
            this.MACartItems = new HashSet<MACartItem>();
            this.MAItemImages = new HashSet<MAItemImage>();
            this.MAOrderDetails = new HashSet<MAOrderDetail>();
        }

        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Discount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Points { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int StoreId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MACartItem> MACartItems { get; set; }
        public virtual MACategory MACategory { get; set; }
        public virtual MAStore MAStore { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MAItemImage> MAItemImages { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MAOrderDetail> MAOrderDetails { get; set; }
    }

public partial class MACategory
    {
        public MACategory()
        {
            this.MAItems = new HashSet<MAItem>();
        }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MAItem> MAItems { get; set; }
    }



 public partial class MAStore
    {
        public MAStore()
        {
            this.MAItems = new HashSet<MAItem>();
            this.MAMembershipCards = new HashSet<MAMembershipCard>();
            this.MAOrders = new HashSet<MAOrder>();
        }

        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Latitude { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MAItem> MAItems { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MAMembershipCard> MAMembershipCards { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MAOrder> MAOrders { get; set; }
    }

public partial class MAItemImage
    {
        public int ItemImageId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string AlternateText { get; set; }

        public virtual MAItem MAItem { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller - MAItemController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("items")]
        public IQueryable<MAItem> GetItems()
        {
            try
            {
                return _service.GetMAItems().AsQueryable<MAItem>();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**Services - MAItemService.cs**

```
 public List<MAItem> GetMAItems()
        {
            string[] Includes = new[] { "MAStore", "MACategory", "MAItemImages" }; 
            List<MAItem> items = new List<MAItem>();
            items = _repository.GetAll(Includes).ToList();
            return items;
        }
```

**Java Script Code**

```
function getAllItem() {
    var req = Object.create(ajax);
    req.parameters = { url: API + '/api/mobileapp/items' };
    req.callback.success = successGetAllItem;
    req.get();
}
function successGetAllItem(data) {
    $(".loading").hide();    
    $.each(data, function (idx, d) {
        alert(d);
    });
}

var ajax = {
    parameters: {
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        loading: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        processData: true,
        timeout: 60000,
        otherData: {}
    },
    callback: {
        success: null,
        error: null
    },
    get: function () {
        this.send('GET');
    },
    post: function () {
        this.send('POST');
    },
    del: function () {
        this.send('DELETE');
    },
    send: function (type) {
        self = this;
        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry|IEMobile/i)) {
            this.loadingIcon.show();

            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.dataType)) this.parameters.dataType = 'json';
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.contentType)) this.parameters.contentType = 'application/json';
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.loading)) this.parameters.loading = false;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.crossDomain)) this.parameters.crossDomain = true;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.async)) this.parameters.async = true;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.processData)) this.parameters.processData = true;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.timeout)) this.parameters.timeout = 30000;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.callback.error)) this.callback.error = this.defaultError;

            return $.ajax({
                type: type,
                url: this.parameters.url,
                dataType: this.parameters.dataType,
                data: (this.parameters.processData) ? JSON.stringify(this.parameters.data) : this.parameters.data,
                processData: this.parameters.processData,
                contentType: this.parameters.contentType,
                crossDomain: this.parameters.crossDomain,
                async: this.parameters.async,
                timeout: this.parameters.timeout,
                success: function (data) {
                    var args = arguments[2];
                    if (!self.isUndefined(self.callback.success)) {
                        if (self.isUndefined(self.parameters.otherData))
                            self.callback.success.call(this, data, args.statusText, args);
                        else
                            self.callback.success.call(this, data, args.statusText, args, self.parameters.otherData);
                    }
                    self.loadingIcon.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    xhrServerObj = xhr;
                    self.callback.error.call(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                    self.loadingIcon.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    },
    isUndefined: function (param) {
        return (typeof param == 'undefined' || param == null);
    },
    defaultError: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    },
    loadingIcon: {
        show: function () {
            if (self.parameters.loading) {
                console.log('Show loading....');
            }
        },
        hide: function () {
            if (self.parameters.loading) {
                console.log('Hide loading....');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please Note: I am able to get the responses from the different methods like `/category`, `/stores`, `/users` but the only issue is with `/items`. This problem also persist in Firefox browser as well.
Can anybody let me know the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Can you post your script code? which is responsible for making this call?

Comment: @MokshShah I have added javascript code as well. Please do let me know still you need any detail from me.

Comment: Look at this answer, it may help :http://stackoverflow.com/a/13459106/1107638

Comment: Actually i was able to get the responses of other methods like `/stores` or `/category` from the same server, moreover it is also showing same message on Firefox browser for `/items` api