# GET document canceled upon first visit (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging, developer-tools

This is a very strange issue with google chrome that some of my customers are reporting that is happening to them when they first visit my website.

Bascially what happens is when they load Chrome for the first time, enter my website domain and press enter. It will load for a second then just delete the URL and show them the page they were at before. Bascially nothing loads.

If they attempt to go to the site again, it will load everything as it should and the site functions normally.

I opened up Developer Tools and discovered that on the first "visit" under the network tab, it shows the document was "canceled".

`example.com` - `GET` - `canceled` - `document`

What would cause chrome to cancel the loading of the whole site on the first time and then let it work as it should after the first time?

Comment: This post seems very similar and could be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

too low rep to put this as comment :( 
but you might want to take a look at
[What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)