# Sometimes Angularjs Cancel my $HTTP request to the server for datatables data

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

Image 2 shows how angular cancel $http but we do not know why.

Because of that we have no JSON data for columns and files from the server and then in the imagen 1 you can see  that angularjs datatables show error

cannot read property of undefined (this is because cannot get columns for datatables i soupose and it is undefined because of that)

Please help me, anybody know why angularjs cancel http???

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this guy's answer, pretty well explained in which scenario a request can get cancelled:
[What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools#answer-13459106)

My best guess is, a DOM element on click of which you made that $http request to get data table, got DELETED before the request is completed.

Comment: I use a form button but i do not delete it   Could it be because I set display hidden but no sense because In other works I did  this is not a problem

Comment: I use angularjs datatables from I-Lin. And i use in the angular way. http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay  coud be that angularjs or this api cancel the http??