# chrome cancel request after 1.5minute

Tags: google-chrome, iis, nginx, xmlhttprequest

After 1.5 minute my send request is cancelled is there any mechanism at browser side which cancel request?

my website hosted on IIS.

[Img for network tab in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdO0W.png)

Comment: You using jQuery?

Comment: No, it's asp.net default xhr POST request

Comment: Then cancelled may mean you request is not responding at all and it is timed out

Comment: No,it's send request to the server but in between process takes time more than 1.5 minutes so request goes to time out.

Comment: Post your XHR JS code that you have used

Comment: My question Is, there any features in chrome which cancel the request after some time(~1.5min) ?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: By default the timeout is 0 in chrome, so the request should not be cancelled until unless something else happened which cancelled the request. I made a request with 100 sec sleep and it worked fine for me