# Angular HTTP API calls timeout intermittently?

Tags: angular, http, typescript, ionic2

As the query implies, API calls being blocked occasionally and doesn't return the response but time out. Not sure what's going on. I did debug to check whether anything wrong with the server side implementation and I have had found that the API request hasn't hitting the server side. Do any one face this before. If then, pl. suggest me any workaround.

**Sample Code:**

```
 this.userProvider.getProfileDetails()
      .subscribe((data: IProviderProfile) => {
        },
        (err: INetworkError) => {
        });
```

Provider

```
getProfileDetails(): Observable<any> {
        return this.apiProvider.authJsonGet(this.config.apiEndpoint + this.config.profileDetailsUrl);
}

public authJsonGet(url: string, params?: URLSearchParams): Observable<any> {
        return this.intercept(url, RequestMethod.Get, this.httpGet(url, params));
  }
```

*Don't be confused, were **intercept** is a custom function which do handle session expire, no big deal inside it.*

Thanking you.

Comment: what is the turn around time for web service?

Comment: I've set *1 minute* as timeout for the calls.

Comment: how much time the service takes to respond? I expect this to be because of the service

Comment: It responds normally sometimes, at some point it doesn't. I tried increasing the time out value but it dint help.

Comment: network calls usually times out after a certain time. [**read here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: I debugged in chrome dev tool, and whenever the issue arises status of the network call indicates as `stalled`, which means it doesn't hitting the server.