# JavaScript: No callback after invoking fetch

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage

I did write a Javascript code to upload a file via API:

```
  function submitForm(bucket, accessToken) {
      console.log("Fetching the file...");
      var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
      var name = input.files[0].name;
      var uploadUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/'+ bucket +'/o?uploadType=media&access_token=' + accessToken +'&name=' + name;
      fetch(uploadUrl, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: input.files[0]
      }).then(function(res) {
          console.log('Something did happen!'); // <<----- Message never displayed!
      });
  }
```

However, I am not able to get the response body from the post request. The upload went well, but without a callback I cannot control the result in a deterministic way. How can I fix it, at least getting the HTTP Status Code?

Comment: Did you get an error in the console?

Comment: No, nothing at all!

Comment: What was the status code in the Network tab?

Comment: try adding a `.catch(err => console.log(err))` - though, you do say there's no error, but it's very unlikely that the promise is neither resolved nor rejected

Comment: `access_tokenn` ... that's unusual spelling, should that be `access_token`? However, none of the examples of using this API never mention this url search parameter. The documentation does show having an `Authorization:` header, which you don't seen to have in your code. Also, all the examples seem to be **not** browser based - perhaps a CORS issue (though, you'd see an error in the console if this were the case) - perhaps you're not looking at the right console?

Comment: Inside the network tab, the action is marked as (cancelled), but the file is actually correctly uploaded. The access token is a misspell here, correct within the app. Also, without the access token no upload happens: with it, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in a very stupid way, by adding:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Source: [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` can generate an error and, if it does, that happens through the `.catch`.

Like this:

```js
function submitForm(bucket, accessToken) {
  console.log("Fetching the file...");
  var name = 'testName';
  var uploadUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/'+ bucket +'/o?uploadType=media&access_tokenn=' + accessToken +'&name=' + name;
  fetch(uploadUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'body stuff'
  }).then(function(res) {
    console.log('Something did happen!'); // <<----- Message never displayed!
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Got error:', err);
  });
}

submitForm('12345', 'testing');
```

Comment: Also adding the catch clause, nothing is being displayed within the console.

Comment: I changed the code to use hardcoded values and I do see the `"Something did happen!"` output. -- Maybe you are getting an exception prior to calling `fetch`.