# Angular http client cancels previous server calls when running in slow connection

Tags: angular, httpclient

So we are facing this issue which seems like a Chrome bug.
When setting Chrome dev tools on 3G slow network and emitting an even from a form control, Chrome will cancel previous network calls EVEN IF the args and params to the server call are different.
We are using Angular 8 latest and I tried different things such as:

```
private onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        this.cdr.detach();
        const values = [];
        this.changed.emit({item: this.m_storeModel, value: values});
        return false;
    }
```

with no luck.
You can see from the image below how Chrome will cancel previous calls.
Firefox works fine.

Anyway to tell Chrome to send ALL CALLS to server and not cancel the call.
I did find other related posts on stackoverflow:
[What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

but no solution works :(

see image below:
[image]

and call is:

```
updateBusinessUserPriv(privilegeId, accessMask, name): Observable<string> {
        const url = `${this.coreAppData[0].webApiResellerBaseUrl}&command=UpdateUserPrivilege&privilegeId=${privilegeId}&accessMask=${accessMask}&customerUserName=${name}`;
        return this._http.get<any>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
            map((result: any) => result)
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code that makes the `http` call

Comment: yes added in original post tx

Comment: as you can see I am not using switchMap