# Scroll load many src images get canceled status

Tags: html, jquery, css, image

I'm using jquery Image Sequencer, on my local machine i have no problem. but when I deployed it on a production server it failed to load the image. please help me for this problem.

[image]

this is my image sequencer code :

```
for (var p = 0; p <= e.count; p++) c.push(e.path + "/" + p + "." + e.ext);
      return t("<div class='jquery-sequencer-preload'></div>").appendTo("body").css("display", "none"), t(c).each(function() {
        t(""+e.element+"").attr("src", this).load(function() {
            t(this).appendTo(""+e.element+""), a++, a === c.length && n()
        })
      }), t(window).scroll(function() {
        s = t(u).height(), 
        r = t(this).height(), 
        o = t(this).scrollTop(), 
        h = e.speedscroll * o / (s - r), i = Math.round(h / 100 * e.count), 
        i < e.count && t("img."+e.sequence).attr("src", c[i])
      }), this
```

Comment: What is the error code? Ex: 404 Not found, 410 unauthorized, etc.

Comment: @Rojo just (canceled)  it doesn't give status

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: thanks @Rojo but how i must solve this problem ? if I must reload so many images and change src if the page have been scrolled ?

Comment: Well, I can't solve anything if there isn't any code to fix. It would help if you shared your code.

Comment: @Rojo i was edit my question and add my code you can check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230311/discussion-between-rojo-and-herdy).